# Local System only ACL in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I am using a named pipe for communications between two processes and want to restrict acess to any user on the local system in Windows.

I am building up and ACL for use in the SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES passed to CreateNamedPipe.

I am basing this code on that from [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/813414).

```
SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY siaLocal = SECURITY_LOCAL_SID_AUTHORITY;
if( !AllocateAndInitializeSid( &siaLocal, SECURITY_LOCAL_RID,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    &pSidLocal ) )
{
    break;
}
```

I then use that sid with AddAccessAllowedAce.

All of this completes successfully and I can create the named pipe however when a client process then tries to connect using CreateFile it fails with access denied.

How do I create an ACL with a SID that allows any user of the local machine to access it?

Comment: In addition to adding an access-denied token for the "network" ACE, I think you need to add an access-allowed token for "everyone" or "authenticated users".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid this is a cross between RTFM and c's complete lack of strict typing.

The second parameter for [`AllocateAndInitializeSid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375213%28VS.85%29.aspx) is actually a count of the sub authorities not the first sub authority.

So by changing the code to:

```
SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY siaLocal = SECURITY_LOCAL_SID_AUTHORITY;
if( !AllocateAndInitializeSid( &siaLocal, 1,
    SECURITY_LOCAL_RID,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    &pSidLocal ) )
{
    break;
}
```

I get the desired results.

I have tested this with different accounts and they can connect and by changing the Authority to `SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY` and the sub authority to `SECURITY_AUTHENTICATED_USER_RID` I was able to connect from another computer to test that this ACL will actually allow and disallow different users.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need an ACL for that.  When calling CreateNamedPipe, one of the parameters takes flag values of PIPE_ACCEPT_REMOTE_CLIENTS (the default) or PIPE_REJECT_REMOTE_CLIENTS.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365150%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Edit:  This is a fairly new feature, so if you're developing for anything but new WS2008 servers it won't work.  The same page has the alternate answer in this case, however: deny access to the pipe to the NETWORK ACE using [AddAccessDeniedAce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374962%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes that flag would be useful but unfortunately this is for a service that needs to run on Windows 2000 and above.

Comment: Too bad, it's always a pain to have to use the security API, in my experience.